# VIM regex - Attempting to fix a JSON file in which the property names aren't quoted

Tags: regex, json, vim

Basically, I'd like to add quotes immediately before and after all property names.

```
propertyName: {
  anotherProperty: "ksdfjslkdfjklsjf",
  someOtherProperty: "aklsjdfljsfdkj"
}
```

I've tried different variations on the following, all to no avail:

```
:%s/A-Za-z:/"A-Zaz-z"
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'd like to become more savvy with regular expressions. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using captures:

```
%s/\([A-Za-z]\+\)\ze:/"\1"/g
```

The result will be:

```
"propertyName": {
  "anotherProperty": "ksdfjslkdfjklsjf",
  "someOtherProperty": "aklsjdfljsfdkj"
}
```

`\(regex\)` is a capture group. Everything that is matched inside can be reused via `\n`. Where `n` is the group index. In my example I have only one capture group, so I use `\1` later.

`\ze` - indicates the end of the match, that way I preserve the colon `:`.

**UPDATE**

Actually @lcd047 solution is better and shorter. `\w` is more preferable for property names, as they may contain digits and underscores:

```
%s/\w\+\ze:/"&"/
```

`\w` is equal to using `[0-9A-Za-z_]`

Comment: This works! Thank you! Could you break down what this regular expression is doing, piece by piece? (I will give you Reddit Gold, if that means anything to you.) Any advice on getting back with regular expressions? They are horrendously cryptic to me.

Comment: Or just `:%s/\w\+\ze:/"&"/` .

Comment: @MichaelP I added some comments. There are many regex tutorials, try to search. My favorite cheat sheet http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/ and visual regex tool http://regexr.com/. But keep in mind that vim regex syntax slightly differs from perl or javascript ones.